# Please explain the behavior of fork in these examples

Tags: linux

See In Example1, the parent process is being called first ,where as in the Example 2 the child process has been called first . I couldn't understand this behavior of fork() .Please clarify.

Example1:

```
main()
{ 
  int pid;
  if((pid=fork())>=0)
  {
     if(pid)
     {
       printf("parent\n");
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Child\n");
     }
  }
  else
    printf("Failed \n");

  if(pid)
    printf("Parent:After fork call\n");
  else
    printf("Child:After fork call\n");

}

O/p:-

 [home]$ ./a.out
 parent
 Parent:After fork call
 [home]$ Child
 Child:After fork call
```

Example 2

```
 main()
 {
   int pid;
   if((pid=fork())>=0)
   {
     if(pid)
     {
       printf("Parent\n");
       system("ls");
     }
     else
     {
       system("pwd");
     }
   }
   else
     printf("Failed \n");

   if(pid)
     system("ps");
   else
     printf("Child:After fork call\n");
 }

O/p:-
 Parent
 /home/neeraj/Vector/OS
 Child:After fork call
 a.out  sendsig    sendsig.c  test2.c  test3.c  test.c
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1943 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 31719 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out
 31720 pts/0    00:00:00 a.out <defunct>
 31723 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: There's no `parent` in the output of the second example?

Comment: See **if(pid)** The 6th line in the code

Comment: There's `printf("parent\n"); system("ls");` in the code of *Example 2*, but I only see `a.out  sendsig    sendsig.c  test2.c  test3.c  test.c` in the output. No `parent`.

Comment: i edited that ,it should be ok now

Comment: If you don't force any ordering, then the ordering can come out any which way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `ls` takes a lot longer than `pwd` to return (`pwd` is just listing a variable in memory where `ls` must talk to the filesystem), that is where the difference is.

This is because you are creating a new thread **and both operations are happening at the same time**, some operations take longer than others. When you where just writing text out you may have had the parent reliably always finish first, but now that you are doing real work whatever thread finished its work first will finish first.